# Avoid Rate limit with rtweet get_timeline()

Tags: r, twitter, parallel-processing

Is there anyway to stop my loop from being interrupted by the rate limit? I would like my code to wait to execute until the time limit has passed if possible.

A side question: I thought about parallelizing the for loop. Do you think this would be a good idea? I was not sure if there would be a chance for data to be written to the wrong file.

```
library(rtweet)
create_token(app="Arconic Influential Followers",consumer_key,consumer_secret) 

flw <- get_followers("arconic")
fds <- get_friends("arconic")
usrs <- lookup_users(c(flw$user_id, fds$user_id))

for(i in 1:length(usrs$user_id)){

    a<-tryCatch({get_timeline(usrs$user_id[i])},
                error=function(e){message(e)}
       )
    tryCatch({save_as_csv(a,usrs$user_id[i])},
                error=function(e){message(e)}
       )

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing was create a while loop that checked the number of records I had left in my Users vector, ran my for loop, and then put the system to sleep for 15 mins. This approach is good, but there are some things to account for. I have the while loop breaking at 200 just in case there were users that didn't have any data to save into a csv. This turned out to be a good move because if you notice the for loop starts iterating at 80. As you start moving across your vector of users the good users are removed iteratively. This leaves only the users that cause errors. An improvement for someone up to the task would be to handle this programatically.

```
Users <- usrs$user_id
goodUsers <- substring(list.files(),1,nchar(list.files())-11)
Users <- setdiff(Users,goodUsers)

while(length(Users)>200){
    for(i in 80:length(Users)){

        a<-tryCatch({get_timeline(Users[i],usr=FALSE)},
                error=function(e){message(e)}
           )
        tryCatch({save_as_csv(a,Users[i])
                goodUsers <- append(goodUsers,Users[i])},
                    error=function(e){message(e)}
        )


    }
Users <- setdiff(Users,goodUsers)
Sys.sleep(900)
}

length(Users)
length(goodUsers)
```

Comment: From [http://rtweet.info/](http://rtweet.info/) "Twitter rate limits cap the number of search results returned to 18,000 every 15 minutes. To request more than that, simply set retryonratelimit = TRUE and rtweet will wait for rate limit resets for you".

Answer (score 5):

I was able to resolve it by wrapping `get_timeline()` function in the following code.
The function `get_timeline_unlimited` calls itself recursively after waiting the required time for the rate limit to reset. So far it worked well for me with no issues.

```
 get_timeline_unlimited <- function(users, n){

  if (length(users) ==0){
    return(NULL)
  }

  rl <- rate_limit(query = "get_timeline")

  if (length(users) <= rl$remaining){
    print(glue("Getting data for {length(users)} users"))
    tweets <- get_timeline(users, n, check = FALSE)  
  }else{

    if (rl$remaining > 0){
      users_first <- users[1:rl$remaining]
      users_rest <- users[-(1:rl$remaining)]
      print(glue("Getting data for {length(users_first)} users"))
      tweets_first <- get_timeline(users_first, n, check = FALSE)
      rl <- rate_limit(query = "get_timeline")
    }else{
      tweets_first <- NULL
      users_rest <- users
    }
    wait <- rl$reset + 0.1
    print(glue("Waiting for {round(wait,2)} minutes"))
    Sys.sleep(wait * 60)

    tweets_rest <- get_timeline_unlimited(users_rest, n)  
    tweets <- bind_rows(tweets_first, tweets_rest)
  }
  return(tweets)
}
```

Comment: Hello! thanks for this function it helped me a lot!!

Comment: i wanted to ask you how it could be possible to modify for list_memberships() method, in this case is valid to pass as a parameter 1 user, no multiple ones