# How to retrieve more than 90,000 users' data using lookup_users() with rtweet package?

Tags: r, rtweet

I'm trying to get all user data for the followers of an account, but am running into an issue with the 90,000 user lookup limit. [The documentation page](https://rtweet.info/reference/lookup_users.html) says that that can be done by iterating through the user IDs while avoiding the rate limit that has a 15 minute reset time, but doesn't really give any guidance on how to do this. How would a complete user lookup with a list of users that is greater than 90,000 be achieved?

I'm using the rtweet package. Below is an an attempt with @lisamurkowski who has 266,000 followers. i have tried using a retryonratelimit = TRUE argument to lookup_users(), but that doesn't do anything.

```
lisa <-  lookup_users("lisamurkowski")
mc_flw <- get_followers("lisamurkowski", n = lisa$followers_count, 
retryonratelimit = TRUE)
mc_flw_users <- lookup_users(mc_flw$user_id)
```

The expected output would be a tibble of all the user lookups, but instead I get

```
 max number of users exceeded; looking up first 90,000
```

And then the outputted object contains 90,000 observations and ends the process.

Comment: When I run the same code with rtweet v0.6.9 (current CRAN version) I get the first 75k followers and then it waits for 15 min to get the next batch.  "Downloading [=========================================] 100%
75000 followers!
Waiting about 15 minutes for rate limit reset..."

Comment: Similar question with a related `rtweet` query, looks like the answers could be adapted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42025979/avoid-rate-limit-with-rtweet-get-timeline

Comment: The above output is for the get_followers() function, which has the argument of retryonratelimit that allows it to keep trying the twitter system. This argument does not exist for lookup_users. The linked thread looks promising, I'll see if I can't adapt that.